# Is there a free historical database of US corporate yields or spreads by maturity buckets?

Tags: data-request, usa, historical

I have US corporate spread data by maturity buckets going back to the 90s but am looking to go back much further, to the 60s. Does anyone know of a freee database which contains that information?